# Making Layouts visible/invisible with Button

Tags: java, android, user-interface, button, android-relativelayout

At the moment I am working on a project for a graphical user interface on an Android tablet. On one screen I have several buttons, which I want to make a `RelativeLayout` visible/invisible with.

I tried using an onClickListener, but in the inner method `onClick` doesn't support non final variables, which I use to select each button and `RelativeLayout`.

The GUI is built dynamically, as its whole structure depends on the data it gets fed via an XML file. Also the `RelativeLayout` uses `TextView`s which receive an update of their textes (sensordata like temperature and humidity), which is why a dynamic approach is used.

Could you give me some ideas for a workaround around that problem? Help is appreciated. If the stated information is not enough for you, just ask and I will give you more details.

At the moment I tried this:

```
private void setSensorPointOnClick(final ObjectView currentObjectView, final String currentLinkName)
{
    for(int i=0; i<listofSensorDeviceButtons.size(); i++ )
    {

        listofSensorDeviceButtons.get(i).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()  
            {
                public void onClick(View v)  
                {
                    arrayClickedButton[i] = listofSensorDeviceButtons.get(i);
                    mainFrameLayout.removeAllViews();
                    stepToObject(currentObjectView, currentObjectView.getName());               
                }
            }
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: add you code to make it simpler.

Comment: What you have try ? First do some google because this is simple

Comment: Couldnt you just build a holder class that has the information you need?

Comment: maybe you can set the layouts as class attributes, so you can access them from OnClick functions and change their visibility.

Comment: Thats a good idea arcastro, Thank you, I am taking a look into it

Comment: José Roberto Araújo Júnior: I have 5 buttons on one view, and set their id's. I also made RelativeLayouts near the button locations, and set their id's. On an ClickEvent, I tried setting these id's. Because I have a dynamic number of buttons, I have to use a for loop. In this for loop, I cant use the current index of the for loop for toggling the visibility of the relative layouts.

Answer (score 0):

either use fields which hold the views that you want to hide/show (and use them in the onClickListener) , or use findViewById within the event handling .

another alternative would be to create another view variable which is final , that will be set just before setting the onClickListener , to hold the reference of the newly created view .

so , in short , the possible solutions i wrote are:

1. use fields .
2. use findViewById
3. use an additional final variable .

Comment: Can I use findViewById when I have a dynamic number of textviews inside the relativelayout? As far as I know, setting the id's to relativelayouts only works in xml, which is static.

Comment: you can use setId for the view . also , you can use the layoutInflater for inflating the views out of xml .

Comment: btw , i think it's silly to use findViewById in case you already have a reference to the view